# Store 2D Array Index in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm coding a Battleship game and I need some way to track where the ships have been placed. I'm thinking the best way of doing this is with an ArrayList. If I store the indices that are contained in a placed ship, then I can iterate through the ArrayList to signify it's an invalid position. For example, if I have a loop like so:

```
for (int j = 1; j < SIZE; j++)
{
   for (int k = 1; k < SIZE; k++)
   {
      if ((cell[j][k].contains(click)))
      {
          cell[j][k].setColor(Color.blue);
      }
   }
}
```

I'd like to store the cell [ j ] [ k ] **position** in an ArrayList, and when it's time for the user to place the ship, a for loop is run to determine whether or not that cell is occupied. The problem is when I try to add to the ArrayList, I'm adding the actual cell, not the index. I want the actual position (x, y) to be stored in the List, but right now I'm storing the actual element.

Comment: You could use Java's point-class or just use your own. Have an `ArrayList<Point>`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

Comment: Array indexing starts from zero. Be careful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need an Arraylist for. Your 2D array has a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a list of x and y values is an ideal situation to use Java's point class.

```
ArrayList<Point> shipPositions = new ArrayList<Point>();
shipPositions.add(new Point(0, 0));
```

The `ArrayList` of points can be easily modified and iterated through to add and remove ship positions.

Comment: So if I wanted to check if the ArrayList contained the point, would I do         `if (!shipPositions.contains(new Point(0,0)`

Comment: Using  `shipPositions.contains(new Point(0,0))` will work just fine to check for a point. I'm not sure if you meant to put the Boolean not (`!`) in though, as this will check if the ArrayList does _not_ contain the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate object for each ship. You could make a rather simple class with an x and a y float (or a Point to keep it simple) and then just make an array of the ships like so

```
Ship[] ships = new Ship[n];
```

or

```
ArrayList<Ship> ships = new ArrayList<Ship>();
```

and then you could get the value at `ships[n]` (for the 1st example) or `ships.get(n)` (for the 2nd example).

This would allow you to use this array for more than just positions and minimize excess and unnecessary code. :)